# Finding letter bigrams in text using Python regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use `re.findall` to find all the sets of two letters following each other in a text (letter bigrams). How do I get the regex not to consume the last letter of the previously found bigram, so that it can be used again in the following?

The following doesn't work, as the regex consumes:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]{2}', 'find bigrams here')
['fi', 'nd', 'bi', 'gr', 'am', 'he', 're']
```

Using a positive lookahead was a second attempt. It doesn't consume the second letter of the previous bigram, but doesn't catch it either...

```
>>> re.findall(r'([a-zA-z](?=[a-zA-Z]))', 'find bigrams here')
['f', 'i', 'n', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'h', 'e', 'r']
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
print re.findall(r'(?=([a-zA-Z]{2}))', 'find bigrams here')
```

Output:`['fi', 'in', 'nd', 'bi', 'ig', 'gr', 'ra', 'am', 'ms', 'he', 'er', 're']`

Guess you need this

Comment: Thanks a lot!! (Of course, for Python 3.x it would be `print(...)`, i.e. with parentheses)

Comment: It works almost everywhere but not Amazon Athena: `select regexp_extract_all('find bigrams here', '(?=([a-zA-Z]{2}))')` returns `{}`

Comment: @BorhanKazimipour not sure if amazon athena support `lookahead`